# regex replace single match from right of string

Tags: php, regex

I need to search and replace in a string, I want to replace the last occurrence of a string.

Here's my working code (which just does a normal search/replace):

```
PREG_REPLACE("/(\b{$abbr}\b)/i", "$long" , $street_address)
```

Example of expected results:

- $street_address = "123 St Martin St"
- $abbr   = "St"
- $long   = "Street"
- return = "123 St Martin Street"

I want only the last occurrence of `St` replaced with `Street`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative lokahead like this:

```
$str = "123 St Martin St";
$abbr="(\b)St(\b)";
$long="Street";
var_dump(preg_replace("~$abbr(?!.*?$abbr)~", "$1" . $long . "$2", $str));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
string(20) "123 St Martin Street"
```

Comment: This worked well and accommodated various variations of abbreviations. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
PREG_REPLACE("/(.*(\b{$abbr}\b.*)*)\b{$abbr}\b/i", "$1$long" , $street_address )
```

This might be relatively inefficient.

Comment: This only works if the string has `st` in it and also ends with `st`.

Comment: Rocket is right -- it depends on the value being present elsewhere in the string.